# TargetNotAMemberException while executing a task using distributed executor service - hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to use the distributed executor service for hazelcast 3.1 and find that i am unable to use submitToMember(**task,member**). In my example below 10.69.108.60 is my local machine and 170.194.100.111 is my remote machine. I am able to get return value in my future when the **member** is my local machine but gives me a **TargetNotAMemberException** if the **member** is remote machine.
Below is the code

```
public class DistExecutionTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        DistributedExecutor dex = new DistributedExecutor();

        try {
            Member member = new MemberImpl(new Address("170.194.100.111",5701), false );

            String msg;
                msg = dex.echoOnTheMember("Hey youuuu!", member);

            System.out.println(msg);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

and

```
public class DistributedExecutor {
        Config config;
        NetworkConfig network;
        JoinConfig join;

    DistributedExecutor(){
        config = new Config();
        network = config.getNetworkConfig();
//      network.setPort(5701);
        join = network.getJoin();
        join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);

        join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("170.194.100.111").addMember("10.69.108.60").setEnabled(true);
        network.getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface("170.194.100.*").addInterface("10.69.108.*");
    }

    public String echoOnTheMember(String input, Member member) throws Exception {
        Callable<String> task = new DistObject(input);
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        IExecutorService executorService = hz.getExecutorService("default");
        Future<String> future = executorService.submitToMember(task, member);
        String distObjectResult = future.get();
        return distObjectResult;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Echo implements Callable<String>, Serializable, HazelcastInstanceAware {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3164053990811643392L;

    String message = null;
    transient HazelcastInstance localInstance;
    public Echo(String msg){
        message = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return localInstance.toString() + message;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        this.localInstance = hazelcastInstance;
    }

}
```

Here is the logging on local machine

```
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:20 PM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: Interfaces is enabled, trying to pick one address matching to one of: [162.124.194.*, 10.38.148.*]
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:20 PM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:20 PM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: Picked Address[10.69.108.60]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Hazelcast Community Edition 3.1 (20131011) starting at Address[10.69.108.60]:5701
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Copyright (C) 2008-2013 Hazelcast.com
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Creating TcpIpJoiner
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Address[10.69.108.60]:5701 is STARTING
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[10.69.108.60]:5703
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[10.69.108.60]:5702
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to /10.69.108.60:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to /10.69.108.60:5702, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[170.194.100.111]:5703
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[170.194.100.111]:5702
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to /170.194.100.111:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to /170.194.100.111:5702, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[170.194.100.111]:5701
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to /170.194.100.111:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:22 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Could not connect to: /10.69.108.60:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: connect to address /10.69.108.60:5703]
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:22 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Could not connect to: /10.69.108.60:5702. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: connect to address /10.69.108.60:5702]
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:22 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Could not connect to: /170.194.100.111:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: connect to address /170.194.100.111:5703]
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:22 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Could not connect to: /170.194.100.111:5702. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: connect to address /170.194.100.111:5702]
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:22 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Could not connect to: /170.194.100.111:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: connect to address /170.194.100.111:5701]
Dec 17, 2013 1:03:23 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] 


Members [1] {
    Member [10.69.108.60]:5701 this
}

Dec 17, 2013 1:03:23 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Address[10.69.108.60]:5701 is STARTED
HazelcastInstance{name='_hzInstance_1_dev', node=Address[10.69.108.60]:5701}Hey youuuu!
```

The logging on the remote machine is on these lines.Couldnt paste all the logging.Managed to get the important part.

```
   INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[10.38.148.60]:5703
    Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
    INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[10.38.148.60]:5702
    Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
    INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[10.38.148.60]:5701
    Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[170.194.100.111]:5703
    Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoiner
    INFO: [10.69.108.60]:5701 [dev] Connecting to possible member: Address[170.194.100.111]:5702
    Dec 17, 2013 1:03:21 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector

    Members [2] {
        Member [10.69.108.60]:5701 this
        Member [170.194.100.111]:5701
    }
```

Comment: It seems that your cluster is forming. Do you see in the other console also Members[2] {....}?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a member instance directly, could you get the member instance using the hz.getCluster().getMembers() method and select the one you want to send to? I want to see if it is caused by the way you are creating that member.

Comment: hz.getCluster().getMembers() only gives my local machine in the Set<Member> that is returned.It doesnt have the remote machine.I was wondering why they are not even forming a cluster. Thats why i went ahead and created the Member object myself.

Comment: Than that is the cause of the exception :) Because you can't send a message to a machine your are not connected to. The big question however is why your cluster is not forming. Can you post your configuration + some of the logging in your original question?

Comment: Posted the exception message in my original question. I am not using xml file for configuration. I am using TcpIpConfig that i am configuring in the code.Is that not enough to form the cluster? Please correct me if i am wrong. I tried excuting the code on 10.69.108.60:5702, another member in the cluster as i see from the logs.And it works.But how do i make the remote machine part of my cluster?

Comment: I think i was expecting the remote machine to be part of the cluster even before i start the same process on the remote machine..I did this 1) start distributedexecutiontest on remote machine.. 2) start distributedexecutiontest on local machine.. 3)then i saw remote machine joining the cluster of local machine and was then able to find it in hz.getCluster().getMembers(). Do you think there is any glitch in the way im configuring members?

Comment: I don't think it is a glitch. Could it be that you send the message to the remote machine, before it joined the cluster?

And could you try to get the correct member from the hazelcastInstance.getCluster().getMembers method? I'm not sure if you are allowed to create an Member the way you did.

Comment: @pventjeer I was sending the message to the remote machine even before it joined the cluster. I got a wrong notion that i can send messages even before the machine joins the cluster because i assumed the tcpipconfig establishes connection and i could send a message no matter what. Thanks for you time.A little confused about how to end this thread and which answer to accept.

Comment: You can't send a message to a remote machine before it joins the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I can't format text in comments, so I'll put another answer.

So the problem you are suffering from is why your members don't form a cluster.

You should see logging like:

```
Members [2] {
    Member [192.168.1.104]:5701 this
    Member [192.168.1.104]:5702
}
```

That is why I need more logging that just your stacktrace, but that currently doesn't provide any more value. I need to see what Hazelcast says about joining other clusters.

I need to see something like this:

```
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder
INFO: Looking for hazelcast.xml config file in classpath.
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder
WARNING: Could not find hazelcast.xml in classpath.
Hazelcast will use hazelcast-default.xml config file in jar.
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder
INFO: Using configuration file     /java/projects/Hazelcast/hazelcast/hazelcast/target/classes/hazelcast-default.xml in the classpath.
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: Picked Address[192.168.1.102]:5701, using socket         ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [192.168.1.102]:5701 [dev] [3.2-SNAPSHOT] Hazelcast Community Edition 3.2-SNAPSHOT (20131217) starting at Address[192.168.1.102]:5701
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [192.168.1.102]:5701 [dev] [3.2-SNAPSHOT] Copyright (C) 2008-2013 Hazelcast.com
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [192.168.1.102]:5701 [dev] [3.2-SNAPSHOT] Creating MulticastJoiner
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:13 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [192.168.1.102]:5701 [dev] [3.2-SNAPSHOT] Address[192.168.1.102]:5701 is STARTING
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:15 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.MulticastJoiner
INFO: [192.168.1.102]:5701 [dev] [3.2-SNAPSHOT] 


Members [1] {
Member [192.168.1.102]:5701 this
}

Dec 17, 2013 7:24:16 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [192.168.1.102]:5701 [dev] [3.2-SNAPSHOT] Address[192.168.1.102]:5701 is STARTED
Dec 17, 2013 7:24:16 PM com.hazelcast.partition.PartitionService
INFO: [192.168.1.102]:5701 [dev] [3.2-SNAPSHOT] Initializing cluster partition table first arrangement...
```

Comment: Thanks. I got some useful information from it. You can see that it can't connect [Connection refused: connect to address /170.194.100.111:5703]. Could it be that you have a firewall up and running? Can you also post the logging of the other machine?

Comment: I clearly ignored the connecton refused message because of certain assumptions. Would u want the logging of the remote machine when the jvm of the local machine is still up(then you can see the local machine clustered with remote)..or u want the logs with just remote machine jvm started and local machine jvm shutdown? There is equal chances of having a firewall up, but im not sure how to confirm.Does the config differ in such a case?

Comment: on one machine call 'iperf -s -p 5701' and on another do 'iperf -c 1.2.3.4 -d -p 5701' set the correct ip. Kill you hazelcast instances before that. This will test if communication is possible at all.

Comment: says command not found.forgot to mention my local machine is windows and remote machine is a linux box(with no root permissions). I should look for alternatives may be

Comment: I don't know another command in combination with windows; haven't used it for many years. My suggestion is to have a look at the firewall settings of your Windows machine (or disable it while you are testing your connectivity problems), and get in contact with the sysadmin of the Linux machine to see if anything has been blocked. Anyway, this is something you need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error.
It is due to this line in `echoonthemember` function

```
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

It creates the new hazelcast instance of default or of cfg config. The member is searched in this instance of the hazelcast which is not actually present in it. Thus the error message is displayed as 
`TargetNotAMemberException`.

To have it work properly, just pass the created instance in the `echoonthemember` function.
E.g by making it the member variable in class `DistributedExecutor` and setting it by the constructor.
then if  your actual instance was `'abcdef'`, then 
use as

```
IExecutorService executorService = abcdef.getExecutorService("default");
```

do not create new `Hazelcast` instance.